# I want To take registration Fee in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I am developing e-commerce website using opencart framework , now i want to take registration fee $25 while registering user , so how i can implement it or any one have extension for that. please help me . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution:

1. Make all the registered customers **inapproved** - thus the administrator has to approve them.
2. Display each customer's ID on the "after-register" confirm page with the information that a registration fee has to be payed to this and that while using their ID as the payment variable symbol (You could format the ID to the code like `000000001`, `000012456`, `0124578963`, etc.).
3. After the customer pays just approve him within the administration...

Automated solution:

1. Let registering user decide how he would like to pay the registration fee (PayPal, transfer, other services).
2. After the registration, while the new customer is still **not approved**, redirect to a pay service (if applicable).
3. After the successful payment (still using the customer's ID as a variable symbol) automatically approve the user within the payment callback.

   - if bank transfer is available You'd still would have to approve them manualy
   - in case of unsuccessful payment You just simply do nothing - user then can re-try the payment and be approved or not...

The second option requires a lot of work to be done (new payment service connections, new callback handlers, registration process modification)...

I have done this once before but I choosed to go with the first (manual and easy to implement) option.

Comment: hey shadyyx, How could admin get notify which customer get paid and which not ?

Comment: If You'd stick just with the first option it is important that the administrator is the person that has access to the bank account or at least he receives that emails about the payments processed. If the payment notification contains the variable symbol (that contains the user's ID) he would then need to find that user and approve him... It's a little more manual work to be done but much less programming needed.